# Node - Can't redirect after query is done processing (or it redirects before it's done processing... or... ahh)

Tags: mysql, node.js, redirect

So I am trying to redirect back to the index once a CSV file has been uploaded and written to the database. I can do one or the other, but not both. If I try both, I get

Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.

Ok, Node is asynchronous. Got it. If I comment out res.redirect('/'); things get posted to the database. And then it hangs on a blank screen... No bueno. So here is my code:

```js
app.post('/upload', function(req,res){
    form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files){
        var path = files['file'][0]['path'];
        var reader = csv.createCsvFileReader(path, {
            'separator': ',',
            'quote': '"',
            'excape': '"',
            'comment': ''
        });
        reader.addListener('data',function(data){
            console.log(data);
            var into = 'import';
            var query = 'INSERT INTO ?? SET student_fname = "' + data[1] + '", student_lname = "' + data[2] + '", student_id = "' + data[4] + '", school_id = "' + data[3] +'", homeroom_id = "'+data[5] +'"';
            connection.query(query, [into],
                function(err, rows){
                    if (err) console.log(err);
                    console.log(rows);
                }
            );         
            //res.redirect('/');
            res.end();
        });

    });

});
```

So firstly I'm aware that there are probably much more elegant ways of doing this, and I'm certainly open to suggestions on that front. We're using a mysql database and we just want teachers to be able to easily upload student data they receive from a website who's api we don't have access to. But assuming that all I want to happen is for this query to run and the user be redirected back to the page they were on, what's the best way to do that? Right now I'm playing around with the async module.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you call `res.redirect('/')` at the end of your query callback?

Comment: That didn't work, but it made me realize I wasn't placing it at the end of everything like I should have done in the first place. I stuck res.redirect and res.end right before the final set of closing tags and everything works now. Thank you!